# Best way to use a listview if it can be automatically updated

Tags: android

I am working on an app that tells on campus activities and arranges them by date. I am a beginning developer and I would like to know if it is better to use the google calendar or a listview. I would rather use a listview but I am not sure on how to have the information automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a handler and a post delayed runnable to refresh the list and call the method to get the data into your listview, over again on a time you set, check link here for reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html